# Replacing text in tags

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have been having problems trying to find a way to replace tags in my strings in Python.

What I have at the moment is the text:

```
you should buy a {{cat_breed + dog_breed}} or a {{cat_breed + dog_breed}}
```

Where `cat_breed` and `dog_breed` are lists of cat and dog breeds.

What I want to end up with is:

```
you should buy a Scottish short hair or a golden retriever
```

I want the tag to be replaced by a random entry in one of the two lists.

I have been looking at `re.sub()` but I do not know how to fix the problem and not just end up with the same result in both tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.sample) to get two unique elements from the population.

```
import random
cats = 'lazy cat', 'cuddly cat', 'angry cat'
dogs = 'dirty dog', 'happy dog', 'shaggy dog'

print("you should buy a {} or a {}".format(*random.sample(dogs + cats, 2)))
```

There's no reason to use regular expressions here. Just use string.format instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the idea below gives you some idea on how to complete your task:

```
list1 = ['cat_breed1', 'cat_breed2']
list2 = ['dog_breed1', 'dog_breed2']


a = random.choice(list1)
b = random.choice(list2)


sentence =  "you should buy a %s or a %s" %(a, b)
```

Comment: Why do you think it does not provide the answer? I have put him on the right track: showed him how to randomly select an item from the list plus how to put it into the string with %s.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like I've made a mistake. Sorry about that.